# Передача объекта из одного класса в другой

Tags: python

```
class timeofpersonedit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Исторический фоторобот")
        self.name = "Какой то текст"
#Здесь записываем события нажатий на кнопку
        self.ui.age1.clicked.connect(self.age_1)
        self.ui.age2.clicked.connect(self.age_2)
        self.ui.age3.clicked.connect(self.age_3)
        self.ui.age4.clicked.connect(self.age_4)


class NewPersonEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.name1 = *ПЕРЕНЕСТИ СЮДА*
        # События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
        # Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)
```

Надо перенести объект self.name из класса в timeofpersonedit в NewPersonEdit как осуществить?

Comment: Опубликовав свой код полностью, вы увеличите получение решения на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Мне надо перенести в def __init__

Comment: `перенести в def init ` - что?

Comment: Из класса timeofpersonedit перенести значение объекта `self.name` в класс NewPersonEdit в объект `self.name1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее правильным решением будет либо конструировать класс на основе необходимого поля:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Name'

class Second:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

first = First()
second = Second(first.name)

print(second.name)
```

Либо, задавать ему необходимое поле через сеттер:

```py
class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

second = Second()
second.set_name("Fedor")
print(second.name)
```